# Where to check the beneficiary got the amount from apple pay -ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, applepay

Where to check the beneficiary got the amount from apple pay in ObjectiveC, I getting the success with payment.token, but i want to check the amount transferred to the merchant , wher i can find this details.

```
PKPaymentRequest*request = [[PKPaymentRequest alloc]init];
        request.merchantIdentifier = @"merchant.com.appName";
        request.supportedNetworks = @[PKPaymentNetworkVisa,PKPaymentNetworkMasterCard,PKPaymentNetworkAmex];
        request.merchantCapabilities = PKMerchantCapability3DS;
        request.countryCode = @"AE";
        request.currencyCode = @"AED";
        PKPaymentSummaryItem *item = [[PKPaymentSummaryItem alloc] init];
                item.label=@"Merchant";
                item.amount=[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1"];
                request.paymentSummaryItems=@[item];
        PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *viewController1 =  [[PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController alloc] initWithPaymentRequest:request];
                viewController1.delegate = self;
                [self presentViewController:viewController1 animated:YES   completion:nil];
```

Comment: It will be in your merchant dashboard.   From your app's point of view, if the payment request completes successfully then the requested amount was paid.

Comment: Can you please guid me where to check merchant dashboard? do i need to check in itunes?

Comment: No, it will be whatever merchant service you use; e.g. Stripe.  Apple isn't involved in processing Apple Pay transactions.  Don't confuse Apple Pay with In App Purchase

Comment: Do i need to integrate any service like stripe. to check this kind of info?

Comment: To use Apple Pay you must have a merchant service to acquire the credit card transaction. Again, make sure you aren't confusing Apple Pay and in app purchase. They are different things.  If you are referring to Apple Pay then I am a little confused; if you get a payment success then the merchant will get the amount in your payment request. This is, of course, subject to standard credit card clearance and there is always the possibility of a chargeback, but that can happen days or weeks after the transaction is posted.

Comment: in Some Info i got that in iTunes connect- Sales and Trends you can see the Transaction list happened ,is that true?

Comment: That is in-app purchase.  Not Apple Pay.  Your question and code refer to Apple Pay, which is used to process credit card transactions for real-world goods and services (e.g. Pizza delivery or ride sharing). App Store Connect has no details on these payments,  These payments are not processed by Apple.  Apple doesn't take a percentage of Apple Pay payments

Comment: Apple Pay Integration using Cybersource,iam not clear about cybersource,Please help me what should i do next with Cybersource, my payments or not reflecting in cybersource.